# Multiple WSL2 distros connected to single X11 server

Tags: xorg, wsl2

I use X11 to start GUI apps in WSL2 distros. For example, here's how it's done with xfce4-terminal:

`wsl --distribution foo --user vect /bin/bash -l -c xfce4-terminal`

`DISPLAY` env variable in the distro is set within `/etc/profile.d/` with the following:

`export DISPLAY="$(sed -n 's/nameserver\ //p' /etc/resolv.conf):0"`

It works fine while there's only one distro GUI apps are started from. Things go weird if I try to start GUI apps from multiple distros. With `bar` distro cloned from `foo` with `wsl --export ...` and `wsl --import ...` I have the following:

in PowerShell

```
wsl --distribution foo --user vect /bin/bash -l -c xfce4-terminal
```

in bash within xfce4-terminal

```
$ echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
foo
```

in PowerShell

```
wsl --distribution bar --user vect /bin/bash -l -c xfce4-terminal
```

in bash within xfce4-terminal

```
$ echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
foo
```

As you can see in the second case `xfce4-terminal` is running in `foo` despite that `bar` is specified.

In the same time when `bash` is started right from `PowerShell` it's running in the right distro:

```
wsl --distribution bar --user vect
$ echo $WSL_DISTRO_NAME
bar
```

The issue is reproduced with `VcXsrv` as well as with `Cygwin/X`.

What am I doing wrong? How to start GUI apps with X11 from multiple WSL2 distros in parallel?

Comment: May I suggest creating a file in the user’s home directories and looking at that instead? Maybe it’s just the variable that’s somehow messed up. // Does a second XFCE Terminal even open?

Comment: @DanielB yes, the second terminal opens. As for files, I tried that and result was the same - the second terminal runs in `foo`.

Comment: Maybe XFCE Terminal finds already-open windows of itself and makes them open the new window instead of launching a new process. // Try with `--disable-server`.

Comment: Yep. `--disable-server` works. It seems that `xfce4-terminal` started in `bar` somehow finds through DBus `xfce4-terminal` running in `foo`. Looks strange for me as I thought that different distros in WSL2 are isolated from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XFCE Terminal has a mechanism where it tries to find running instances using DBus. This behavior can be disabled using `--disable-server`.

---

All WSL 2 distributions run in a single virtual machine. They also [share a single network namespace](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4304):

[image: two terminals, two distribution, same network config]

I’m not familiar with DBus, but I see that it supports TCP transports. UNIX socket would probably not be shared between WSL 2 distributions due to different namespaces for:

- ipc
- mnt
- pid & pid_for_children
- uts

However, it’s feasible for DBus connections to go to another distribution via TCP. That could cause *interesting* behavior when using desktop software.